# Adding text other than the selected text options to the select with the Chosen plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using [the chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Adding this to my document does not enable me to type into the text field and add a new item to the list.

```
$(document).ready(function (){    
    $(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

This will allow some hard coded text to be added to the list:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.chosen-select').chosen();
    $('.addsomething').click(function (){
        $(".chosen-select").prepend("<option>Utopia</option>");
        $(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
});
```

What I would like to see happen is I would like to be able to add text to the text field, hit return and have my entry be added if I have not chosen it.  It does not need to be permanently added to the options list.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not sure if it can be done in an easier way, but this works just fine. The comments from the code explain each step:

```
var select, chosen;

// Cache the select element as we'll be using it a few times
select = $(".chosen-select");

// Init the chosen plugin
select.chosen({ no_results_text: 'Press Enter to add new entry:' });

// Get the chosen object
chosen = select.data('chosen');

// Bind the keyup event to the search box input
chosen.dropdown.find('input').on('keyup', function(e)
{
    // If we hit Enter and the results list is empty (no matches) add the option
    if (e.which === 13 && chosen.dropdown.find('li.no-results').length > 0)
    {
        var option = $("<option>").val(this.value).text(this.value);

        // Add the new option
        select.prepend(option);
        // Automatically select it
        select.find(option).prop('selected', true);
        // Trigger the update
        select.trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jHvmg/436/

Comment: is thee a solution that you know of that would work with the multi select version?

Comment: I had to adapt the code (just how the search field is found) in the latest chosen-select version.

Instead of `chosen.dropdown.find('input')` I had to use `chosen.search_field`.

And it works fine on multiple select.

Comment: `chosen.search_field.on('keyup', function(e)` works for multiple select

Answer (score 13):

I modified [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18707331/2656413) from Bogdan to work with chosen 1.2.0 as well as with all types of chosen selects:

```
var select, chosen;

// cache the select element as we'll be using it a few times
select = $(".chosen-select");

// init the chosen plugin
select.chosen();

// get the chosen object (any type, single or multiple)
chosen = $('.chosen-container');
// chosen = $('.chosen-select-single');
// chosen = $('.chosen-container-multi');

// Bind the keyup event to the search box input
chosen.find('input').keyup( function(e)
{
    // if we hit Enter and the results list is empty (no matches) add the option
    if (e.which === 13 && chosen.find('li.no-results').length > 0)
    {
        var option = $("<option>").val(this.value).text(this.value);

        // add the new option
        select.prepend(option);
        // automatically select it
        select.find(option).prop('selected', true);
        // trigger the update
        select.trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
});
```

Comment: Works great. I'd also suggest changing the default text to tell the user to press enter to add the new element. Just pass in `{no_results_text: 'Press enter to add:'}` when initializing chosen.

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative is to use select2, which has tags build in:
https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags

```
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
  tags: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an article here how to add new values to a chosen select list here:

https://boundlessjourney.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/adding-new-values-to-chosen-plugin/

Basically you edit the chosen.jquery.js file and search for `case 13:` and replace the code in the switch case with

```
case 13:
 evt.preventDefault();
 if (this.results_showing) {
   if (!this.is_multiple || this.result_highlight) {
     return this.result_select(evt);
   }
   $(this.form_field).append('<option>' + $(evt.target).val() + '</option>');
   $(this.form_field).trigger('chosen:updated');
   this.result_highlight = this.search_results.find('li.active-result').last();
   return this.result_select(evt);
  }
  break;
```

This is for multiselects but in my case, I wanted to be able to add a single option. I found the answer in the comments but it was missing code and I add the ability to capitalise each word.

This can be done by replacing the code in the switch case with:

```
case 13:
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (this.results_showing) {

    if (this.result_highlight) {
      return this.result_select(evt);
    }
    $(this.form_field).append('<option>' + ($(evt.target).val()).replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();}) + '</option>');
    $(this.form_field).trigger('chosen:updated');
    this.result_highlight = this.search_results.find('li.active-result').last();
    return this.result_select(evt);
  }
  break;
```

Maybe the code can be edited so it can accept both multiselects and single

Answer (score 0):

In `chosen.jquery.js` file in  `AbstractChosen.prototype.choice_label` funciton you can change selected text

Like this

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.choice_label = function(item) {
      if (this.include_group_label_in_selected && (item.group_label != null)) {
        return "<b class='group-name'>" + (this.escape_html(item.group_label)) + "</b>" + item.html;
      } else {
          return item.html.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "");;//Ashkufaraz Remove Post From Selected Text
      //  return item.html;
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

simple code

```
    var VAL = 1;
    var NM = "Aladein";
    $("#YourID").append('<option value="' + VAL + '">' + NM + '</option>');
    $("#YourID option:selected").val(VAL);
    $("#YourID option:selected").text(NM);
    $('#YourID').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Answer (score -2):

`$('.choose').chosen();`

`$('.choose').on('chosen:no_results',function(evt, params)`{
`var value = params.chosen.search_results.find('span').text();`
`$('.choose').append(new Option(value, value,true).outerHTML);`
`$('.choose').trigger("chosen:updated");`
`});`